# Use of (apparently) empty C function

Tags: c, void

Can anyone comment on the point of the following function, which appears to do not very much:

```
// Returns stored values
int getDetails(const int param1[],
               int* param2,
               int* param3,
               int* param4)
{
    (void)param1;
    (void)param2;
    (void)param3;
    (void)param4;
    return 0;
}
```

The comment is actually there with the code. I'm thinking it must be some kind of odd stub but it is being called and I'm racking my brains to try to imagine what I'm missing.

My best hunch so far is that the function has been deprecated but not removed and the `(void)param` is to avoid compiler warnings about unused variables.

Answer (score 5):

Statements like `(void)param1;` are typically used to suppress warnings about unused function parameters.  (As an aside, in C++ you could also comment out or remove the parameter names.)

You're correct that the function does nothing.  If other code doesn't create a pointer to it, you could safely remove it.

Comment: omitting parameter names in prototypes that are part of a definition is a C++-ism

Answer (score 4):

It's an empty function. Casts to `void` suppress warnings about unused parameters.

Such functions are often used when a function must be called unconditionally or a valid function pointer must be provided, but really the function has nothing to do.

I have a few such functions in my compiler's code generator. There are two code generators actually, one for x86 and the other for MIPS. I compile and link one or the other, never both at the same time.

The code generators are different internally but have the same external API. So, some functions specific to one CPU have some work to do while the same functions for the other have nothing to do. Logically, some of them are empty since there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 2):

My guess (opinion - sorry!) that it could be a stub as you say.  If you have a function that takes one or more function pointers to achieve something and it does not allow for a NULL (don't bother with this) then you have to provide something for it to call.

The casts are probably to avoid the "unused parameter" warning.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it has no point.

All it does is explicitly ignore the arguments by evaluating them and casting the result to `(void)`, and return 0.

Is the return value being used in the context of the call? The best approach is of course to remove the call and replace it with a 0 if the return value is being used, and test the program.

Comment: You are likely right, but from the (lack of) context we can not be certain it has no point. It could be the stop function in a list of functions pointers, for instance. Something like "`if (0==p(param1, param2, param3, param4))`" stop doing stuff.

Comment: The context is definitively the key here. From my privileged position of being able to see the rest of the code, I can see that fortunately, function pointers are not being used here so it is safe to remove. The lesson I take from this is that it's important to comment the context and intention of a change so that future readers understand the *purpose* of the code. It's an old adage, but clearly worth repeating - If I had a pound for every time I've said it, I wouldn't have to fix other peoples code any more! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some Compilers shows error/warning when you are not using the arguments passed to it , to avoid that mention that like it in your code . If the function is not called any where or not assigned to any function pointers , you can remove it as it is not doing anything specific